# JavaScript regex to match one of several classnames in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have a string that can be one of the following, or none, and I'm trying to test to see if one of two class names exists in the string.

```
<span class="italic bold">beatae</span>
<span class="bold italic">beatae</span>
<span class="bold">beatae</span>
<span class="italic">beatae</span>
```

A successful match should mean the string is a complete span tag with one of those two class names on it. Ideally I'd like string.match to return the class names (italic, bold, or both) if possible.

The most related post I found on here is this: [Need Regexp for classname replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635927/need-regexp-for-classname-replace) I tried adapting the regex to fit my needs but I'm missing something.

This is what I have so far:

```
/^<span class="(bold|italic)">[^<]*<\/span>$/i
```

But I always get null for matches. Thanks in advance!

Edit: It's an actual string in Javascript, not a DOM node, so its equivalent to;

```
var mystring = '<span class="bold italic">beatea</span>';
var matches = mystring.match( /regex/ );
```

Comment: What do you match against?

Comment: You could use jQuery for this. `if($('span').hasClass('italic') || $('span').hasClass('bold'))`

Comment: You need to add some context. Are you using outerHTML to get the string, className, or what ?

Comment: I think an important question is "what are you trying to do in general?"

Comment: Basically I'm working on a text editor (contenteditable) and I'm comparing the users selection to toggle editor buttons. If the selection includes classes, I depress the buttons so the UI matches the selection. The selection is returned as a string of HTML that I'm comparing against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on:

```
/^<span\sclass="[\w\s]*(bold|italic)+[\w\s]*">[^<]*<\/span>$/i
```

You forgot to match any additional classes that might occur, which is what the additional `[\w\s]*` are about.

**UPDATE**

Since you can not do [repeating groups in javascript regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp), you have to match the string multiple times for each class you want to get if you want to get *both* classes in group results (preferrably via `indexOf` because `RegExp` is useless in this case):

```
 var classesToMatch = ['italic', 'bold'],
     matchedClasses = [],
     htmlString = "<span class='bold italic'>beatae</span>";
 for (var i = 0; i < classesToMatch.length; i++) {
   if (htmlString.indexOf(classesToMatch[i]) > -1) {
     matchedClasses.push(classesToMatch[i]);
   }
 }
```

`matchedClasses` will contain all matched classes.

Comment: Very close, with a test string with both class names .match returns an array with the original string as match[0], and match[1] is italic. It's missing the bold class.

Comment: Update works perfect now thanks! I didn't realize JS can't do that, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need regexp. It's better to work with element you need:

```
var array = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); // get all span elements
//check each span element for class 'italic' or 'bold'
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if((array[i].className.indexOf('bold') != -1) || (array[i].className.indexOf('italic') != -1))  {
    //if there are our classes - do something with this span
    console.log(array[i]); // array[i] - is a span which contains certain classes
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a DOM node, it's a string. Thanks though.